# Android Fatal Exception Google Maps API 2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-fragmentactivity

I am unsure of the errors that I am getting when I try to launch this app on a tablet. I have implemented all the correct permissions, meta-data and implemented the correct API key inside the manifest. I have also done everything needed inside the mainactivity and the layout. Please read the error log below and let me know whats happening, thank you in advance.

//error log

```
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095): Process: com.example.googlemapapp, PID: 3095
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapapp/com.example.googlemapapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class fragment
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class fragment
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.example.googlemapapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     ... 11 more
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find dynamic class com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.a(Unknown Source)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.U(Unknown Source)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.S(Unknown Source)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.mA(Unknown Source)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2158)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
12-05 06:03:41.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3095):     ... 21 more
```

//manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example.googlemapapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.googlemapapp.maps.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
        android:protectionLevel ="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemapapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="false" /> 


        <meta-data 
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="hidden" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

//mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.googlemapapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
EditText TXTA, TXTB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TXTA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        TXTB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

//mainactivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.googlemapapp.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/b" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Enter Data below"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Search" />

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lineartab" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

//api settings 
[image: API settings]

//I've uploaded the entire project if anyone wants to download and help me figure this out

http://phototitan.net/by3tga2vshxv

Answer (score 2):

Use the mapFragment element as below in the `xml`

```
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lineartab" />
```

Because the API version is beneath 11, SupportMapFragment is used instead of MapFragment.

[image]

You need to check the project properties:

1. Does `Google API's` selected?
2. Google play service lib project added?

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the effort, I have made the above change but I am still getting the same errors. I will modify the log above.

Comment: @ssj3goku878 still facing issue?

Comment: yes, I have added the element as you said and I still get errors, I updated the error log above with the errors i am getting with your code. Thanks

Comment: Yup! Google API's is selected along with the google play services. Will update with an image if it'll let me post that.

Comment: I've added an image of my settings so you can see what I have going on

Comment: Here I can send you the entire project so you can test it out if you'd like. I've uploaded it here http://phototitan.net/by3tga2vshxv

Answer (score 1):

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/lineartab" />
```

You are usin Inner fragment I think that is the problem. Instead of using fragment You should use com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView and try.

Comment: thank you but its no good, I still get similar errors except with MapView instead of SupportMapFragment.

Comment: You need to use this instead of <fragment />.  <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/frMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: yes that is correct since I am using an SDK lower than 11.